# How much is Unicornify costing Stack Overflow the company (if at all)?

Tags: discussion, april-fools, business-model, unicornify

I just took a look at the rates table for [Google App Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) and this question popped into my head:

[image: Rates table]

Comment: Ask this horse, of course of course: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha

Comment: If no more new images are rendered then we'll know it's not paid for at all...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because this is about the 2010 April Fool's joke, Unicornify. Since it was undeployed on the sites shortly afterwards, questions about it aren't relevant anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, this is really weird. In my administration console it looks different than in yours.

[Resource Allocations http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/4647/billing.png](http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/4647/billing.png)

Comment: Any chance you kept the image somewhere? Imageshack nuked it long ago.